# how to create tree hierarchy in rdlc reports

Tags: c#, rdlc

We have a rdlc report with a dataset containing an item data with its category and group.  We need to create a tree hierarchy in the table, where it first displays the categories of the item ,below it the groups in that category and further below it the material s in that group.

Answer (score 0):

You should use column wise grouping on a table or matrix. You can add detail to a column group based on Category with a child column group based on CategoryGroups and finally a child column group based on the Materials.

**NOTE** : If you keep a group headers and footers at each level and put in dummy labels this will allow you to visually identify the report boundaries and build out your report. You can then remove the dummy columns.